# get key from value python

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, key

I have a txt file with a lot of lines like this

```
369136986 cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN/CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_8/branchController05/easyCrate1/easyBoard03/channel002
```

Two columns where the first has numbers, and the second column a line with properties separated by `/`, both columns are separated by space.

I did a dictionary of dictionaries where the key1 is
the first number that appears in the line  (`369136986`), this key has as a value the other dictionary, where the keys are `cmstrk`, `trackersy`, `branch`, `crate`, `board`, `channel` and each of these keys key has as a value `cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN`, `CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_8`, `branchController05`, `easyCrate1`, `easyBoard03`, `channel002`, respectively, so if you ask `cmstrk` (key2) for `369136986` (key1) it returns  `cms_trk_dcs_05` (value).

How can I get the key by giving the value? I mean if I give the value `CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_8` I need to know to which key1 corresponds (the program should return `369136986`).

This is what i tried:

```
input3=raw_input("Write the property(s) which modules connected you want to know, separated by a single space \n > ")
input_list3=input3.split(' ')
for k in input_list3:
    print "%r" % k
    txt.write("\t\n The modules with property %r are:\n" % k)
    for l,m in zip(HVInfoDict.keys(),HVInfoDict.values()):
        if k == HVInfoDict[l][m]:
            print l
```

but it returns

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

so how can I get the first key?

Comment: Does changing the if statement to `if k in m.values():` get you what you want?

Comment: Could you put an example of the input dictionary that's a little easier to cut-and-paste? The problem here is that `m` is sometimes a dictionary, which can't be used as a key to another dictionary.

Comment: Also you can replace `zip(HVInfoDict.keys(),HVInfoDict.values())` by `HVInfoDict.items()`, as it will return same list of tuples.

Comment: David Robinson, yes i had to look in m.values, thank you!

Comment: jonrsharpe, now it is solved thanks to David Robinson and Jhon Rudell, thanks for your comment. pavel_form thanks to you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m is the whole dictionary thats retured in HVInfoDict[l].. you need to look at the values inside of m like so.

```
HVInfoDict = {
    369136986: {
        'cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN',
        'trackersy': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_8',
        'branch': 'branchController05',
        'crate': 'easyCrate1',
        'board': 'easyBoard03',
        'channel': 'channel002'
    }
}

input3 = raw_input("Write the property(s) which modules connected you want to know, separated by a single space \n > ")
input_list3 = input3.split(' ')
for k in input_list3:
    print "%r" % k
    txt.write("\t\n The modules with property %r are:\n" % k)
    for l,m in HVInfoDict.items():
        if k in m.values():
            print l
        else:
            print("Does not exist!")
```

output:

```
Write the property(s) which modules connected you want to know, separated by a single space 
 > branchController05 CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_8 channel002 abcdefg
'branchController05'
369136986
'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_8'
369136986
'channel002'
369136986
'abcdefg'
Does not exist!
```

Comment: Jhon Rudell you are correct i was looking in the wrong place, thanks a lot for your ansewer, my script now works!